# How to automate with for loop inside array from a jquery element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to automate with the help of `for` loop an array for 10 image files in `initialPreview` and `initialPreviewConfig` parameters.

Something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  "<img style='height:35px' id=' + zerofill(i,2) +' src='" + url + zerofill(i,2) +"'.png'>"
}
```

**But how can I implement that in code bellow?**

```
initialPreviewShowDelete: false,
initialPreview: [
    "<img style='height:35px' id='01' src='" + url + "01.png'>",
    "<img style='height:35px' id='02' src='" + url + "02.png'>",
    "<img style='height:35px' id='03' src='" + url + "03.png'>",
    "<img style='height:35px' id='04' src='" + url + "04.png'>",
    "<img style='height:35px' id='05' src='" + url + "05.png'>",
    "<img style='height:35px' id='06' src='" + url + "06.png'>",
    "<img style='height:35px' id='07' src='" + url + "07.png'>",
    "<img style='height:35px' id='08' src='" + url + "08.png'>",
    "<img style='height:35px' id='09' src='" + url + "09.png'>",
    "<img style='height:35px' id='10' src='" + url + "10.png'>",
],
initialPreviewConfig: [
    {caption: "01", width: "35px", url: "avatar_ajax.php", key: 1},
    {caption: "02", width: "35px", url: "avatar_ajax.php", key: 2},
    {caption: "03", width: "35px", url: "avatar_ajax.php", key: 3},
    {caption: "04", width: "35px", url: "avatar_ajax.php", key: 4},
    {caption: "05", width: "35px", url: "avatar_ajax.php", key: 5},
    {caption: "06", width: "35px", url: "avatar_ajax.php", key: 6},
    {caption: "07", width: "35px", url: "avatar_ajax.php", key: 7},
    {caption: "08", width: "35px", url: "avatar_ajax.php", key: 8},
    {caption: "09", width: "35px", url: "avatar_ajax.php", key: 9},
    {caption: "10", width: "35px", url: "avatar_ajax.php", key: 10},
],
```

Comment: Mario Ene. Please provide us the code rather than a screenshot of the code. Additionally, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method on every iteration of `for` cycle, to add items to the array. Like this:

```
var initialPreviewArray = []; 
var initialPreviewConfigArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  initialPreviewArray.push("<img style='height:35px' id='" + zerofill(i,2) + "' src='" + url + zerofill(i,2) +"'.png'>");
  initialPreviewConfigArray.push({
      caption: zerofill(i,2),
      width: "35px",
      url: "avatar_ajax.php",
      key: i
  });
}
```

And assign it to needed property:

```
 $("#inputFile").fileinput({
     uploadUrl: "avatar_upload.php", 
     uploadAsync: true, 
     minFileCount: 1, 
     owerwriteInitial: false, 
     showClose: true, 
     showCaption: true, 
     initialPreviewShowDelete: false,
     initilPreview: initilPreviewArray
     initialPreviewConfig: initialPreviewConfigArray,
     uploadExtraData: {
         img_key: "1000", 
         img_keywords: "happy, people"
     },     
});
```

Also, you should better use `var i = 0` istead of just `i` in for loop. `var` statement makes the variable local, otherwise it gets in global scope and one day could harm you very much. And pay attention to quote escape when you generate your string. I've fixed a mistake there too.

Comment: Thank You for quick reply!  Code `initialPreviewArray.push("<img style='height:35px' id='" + i + "' src='" + url + zeroFill(i,2) +".png'>");` is working super ok. But `initialPreviewConfigArray.push({
      caption: zerofill(i,2),
      width: "35px",
      url: "avatar_ajax.php",
      key: i
  });` is not working.

Comment: I've committed a typo there. `initialPreviewConfig` instead of `initialPreviewCongif`.

Comment: I corrected that issue, but second array is not working.

Comment: It's working now! Thank you very much for the solution. The error was also from 'var initialPreviewConfigArray' typo.